# How to mark Hibernate bean property as @Transient on Java 6?

Tags: java, hibernate, java-7, java-6, hibernate-4.x

I have an application that I am being forced to host on a provider that only runs JRE 6.

I get a compilation error on my Hibernate beans that have properties that have been annotated with `@Transient`.  The compilation error is due to the fact that `java.beans.Transient` was introduced in Java 7.

Is there a way to mark a Hibernate property as transient without this annotation?  Preferably without having to migrate fully to `*.hbm.xml` and abandon annotations altogether?  Would it be possible to somehow add just this annotation interface to the classpath of JRE 6 somehow?

*If you would like to point out this is impossible on Java 6 and that I should switch hosting providers then please post this as a comment, answers stating this will be downvoted.*

Answer (score 3):

Try to mark the property as transient, e.g.

```
private transient int x;
```

Comment: It seems so obvious!  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
import javax.persistence.Transient;
```

However, not sure if it will work in hibernate without JPA mode.